# Type error Instantiating class extending abstract class

Tags: python, typeerror, abstract

I have an abstract class defined

```
class AbstractClass(object):
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta

    @abstractmethod
    def method_a(self):
        pass

    def method_b(self):
        pass
```

And I have a class extending from the abstract clas

```
class MyClass(AbstractClass):

    logger = get_my_logger() # util function return logger from logger pool

    def method_a(self):
        # do something
        return None
```

And I have a helper class instantiating `MyClass` in classmethod

```
class HelperClass(object):
    logger = # get logger

    @classmethod
    def init_my_class(cls):
        my_class = MyClass()
```

When I call `HelperClass.init_my_class` in a module I am getting `TypeError` with message `TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class MyClass with abstract methods logger`

```
#module.py
logger = # get logger

def init():
    HelperClass.init_my_class()
```

I am confused because logger is not an abstract method but the error message saying it is. `logger` is used in `MyClass`, `HelperClass`, and the module (calling HelperClass) not sure if having the same name `logger` in the classes causing the issue.

If I remove `logger` from `MyClass` then the issue resolves, but, I do need to keep the logger.

Comment: Please make sure your [mcve] actually reproduces the problem. I currently highly doubt that it does (`MyClass.method_a()` is missing `self`, for starters).

Comment: updated that MyClass.method_a() has `self`

Comment: The error message tells you that your *abstract base class* defines a method with the name `logger` decorated either with `abstractmethod` or `abstractproperty`, that hasn't been implemented by the concrete subclass. Your sample base class does not have such an abstract method or property definition.

Comment: In other words, I can't reproduce this issue with the code shown here. What version of Python is this with?

Comment: it's python 2.7

Comment: Sorry, can't reproduce this in either 2.7 or 3.6.

Comment: What does `print AbstractClass.__abstractmethods__` produce? Same for `MyClass.__abstractmethods__`.

Comment: updated information - I found another abstract class has an abstract method `logger` - would that be an issue?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the issue.

Comment: @MartijnPieters they came up with a [mcve] that helped solve it: http://stackoverflow.com/q/39734444/3001761

Comment: @jonrsharpe: thanks for the heads-up!