# TypeError in custom defined NullObject

Tags: python, abstract-class, typeerror

I have an abstract class defined

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod

class AbstractClass(object):
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta

    @abstractmethod
    def method_a(self):
        pass
```

And I have a class extending from the abstract class

```
class NullObject(object):

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return lambda *args, **kwargs: None


class MyClass(AbstractClass):

    logger = NullObject()

    def method_a(self):
        return None
```

And if I try to init `MyClass` then I get:

```
>>> a = MyClass()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class MyClass with abstract methods logger
```

If I assign `object()` instead of `NullObject()` to `logger` then the problem resolves but I wanted to understand why the `NullObject` is causing the `TypeError`.

Comment: I am using python 2.7

Comment: Hmm actually I *do* get the same error in 3.x

Comment: Although I've run out of votes to mark this a dupe, there's an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28202339/3001761. You have the same problem as PyMongo apparently once had, as your `__getattr__` interferes with the checking of `logger. __isabstractmethod__`. You can therefore fix it by setting `__isabstractmethod__ = False` on `NullObject`.

Comment: Thanks for producing a valid MCVE. As John points out, you have the same problem as identified in another question; your NullObject produces a truthy object for any attribute lookup so tests as an abstractmethod object.